# How to get python to successfully download large images from the internet

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, urllib

So I've been using

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL, FILENAME)
```

to download images of the internet. It works great, but fails on some images. The ones it fails on seem to be the larger images- eg. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQkbJ.jpg. It downloads them fine, but when I try to open these files photo viewer gives me the error "windows photo viewer cant open this picture because the file appears to be damaged corrupted or too large".

What might be the reason it can't download these, and how can I fix this?

EDIT: after looking further, I dont think the problem is large images- it manages to download larger ones. It just seems to be some random ones that it can never download whenever I run the script again. Now I'm even more confused

Comment: This doesn't have to mean that the Python code is broken. It could be that the image inherently can't be opened by Windows Photo Viewer but that somehow the browser is better at it.

Comment: As @AHuman posted, use urlopen instead of urlretrieve. HTH.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I can manually download that image, and open it in photo viewer just fine.

Comment: and @AnneLagang I don't think that's still in Python 3 to the same functionality

Comment: Added sample Python3 code using urlopen.

Answer (score 3):

In the past, I have used this code for copying from the internet. I have had no trouble with large files.

```
def download(url):
    file_name = raw_input("Name: ")
    u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    f = open(file_name, 'wb')
    meta = u.info()
    file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
    print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)  
    file_size_dl = 0
    block_size = 8192
    while True:
        buffer = u.read(block_size)
        if not buffer:
            break
```

Comment: You beat me to it! I was about to tell the OP to use urlopen instead of urlretrieve.

Comment: hmm, anything for python 3?

Comment: how do you specify where it saves with urlopen?

Comment: @user3662991 Are you talking about the file or the url?

Comment: The file- with urlretrieve you put the filename / parth and find the image there. I'm not sure how to do this with urlopen

Comment: @user3662991   The program asks for the filename. It then creates that file. And when it is done it is done. I probably should close the file though.

Comment: @user3662991 Instead of writing just the filename, you can specify add the full path and pass it as the first parameter in open(filenameWithPath, 'wb').

Answer (score 1):

Here's the sample code for Python 3 (tested in Windows 7):

```
import urllib.request

def download_very_big_image():
    url = 'http://i.imgur.com/DEKdmba.jpg'
    filename = 'C://big_image.jpg'
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    output = open(filename, 'wb') #binary flag needed for Windows
    output.write(conn.read())
    output.close()
```

For completeness sake, here's the equivalent code in Python 2:

```
import urllib2

def download_very_big_image():
    url = 'http://i.imgur.com/DEKdmba.jpg'
    filename = 'C://big_image.jpg'
    conn = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    output = open(filename, 'wb') #binary flag needed for Windows
    output.write(conn.read())
    output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work: use `requests` module:

```
import requests

img_url = 'http://i.imgur.com/DEKdmba.jpg'
img_name = img_url.split('/')[-1]
img_data = requests.get(img_url).content
with open(img_name, 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img_data)
```