# Python urlretrieve fails to download some images

Tags: python, image, python-3.x

I'm having trouble with downloading certain images using urlretrieve.

I use this code snippet to download image:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.facebook.com/photo/download/?fbid=166644340383715','image_name.jpg')
```

Downloads successfully, just like as other images, but when I'm trying to open it, I got error: `Unknown file format, empty/damaged file or file not found` what does not happen when I try to download that exact image via browser just copypasting URL `https://www.facebook.com/photo/download/?fbid=166644340383715` to address line and pressing enter. File size is also different: actual file is 14.6 KB large and file created with urlretrieve is 48 KB. I decided that this problem is related to small files only, but tried with another file <20 KB and it downloaded successfully.

I tried to use solution for similar problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26878296/4279419), i. e. use code:

```
def download_image(url, filename, output_dir_name):
    if not os.path.exists(output_dir_name):
        os.makedirs(output_dir_name)
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    output = open(os.path.join(output_dir_name, filename), 'wb')  # binary flag needed for Windows
    output.write(conn.read())
    output.close()
```

for images downloading, but result is the same (could not open resulting file). Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the image on the server side is broken. Or the server blocks your downloading. Either way it is hopeless for your to download this image.