# How to read image of google drive using python

Tags: python, odoo

I want to read image from google drive and store in binary field.How can I do that?
I tried this code but I got too large image.Another option for reading image from drive?

```html
link = urllib.request.urlopen(image_path).read()
image_base64 = base64.encodestring(link)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get python to successfully download large images from the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876628/how-to-get-python-to-successfully-download-large-images-from-the-internet)